# How to remove Facebook's "Thought the group would like this"

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups

For the Facebook users, a new "feature" was invented: when you share a post in a group, a automatic message

> Thought the group would like this

appears as the default message.

Is there a way to get rid of this, in order do not have any default message of sharing in a Facebook group?